# Is there any point of using connection pools with a non multi threaded web server?

Tags: python, flask, heroku, concurrency, gunicorn

I have built a webserver written in python using the flask framework and psycopg2 and I have some questions about concurrent processing as it relates to dbs and the server itself. I am using gunicorn to start my app with
`web:gunicorn app:app`.

From my understanding a webserver such as this processes requests one at a time. So, if someone makes a get or post request to the server the server must finish responding to that get or post request before it can then move on to another request. If this is the case, then why would I need to make more than one connection cursor object? For example, if someone were making a post request that requires me to update something in the db, then my server can't process requests until I return out of that post end point anyway so that one connection object isn't bottle necking anything is it?

Ultimately, I am trying to allow my server to process a large number of requests simultaneously. In order to do so, I think I would first have to make multiple instances of my server, and THEN the connection pool comes into play right? I think in order to make multiple instances of my server (apologies if any terminologies are being used incorrectly here), I would do one of these things:

one way would be to: I would need to use multiple threads and if the machine my application is deployed on in the cloud has multiple cpu cores, then it can do this(?). However, I have read that python does not support "True multithreading" meaning a multi threaded program is not actually running concurrently, it's just switching back and forth between those threads really quickly, so would this really be any different than my set up currently?

the second way: use multiple gunicorn workers, or use multiple dynos. I think this route is the solution here, but I don't understand the theory on how to set this up at all. If I spawn additional gunicorn workers, what is happening behind the scenes? Would this still all run on my heroku application instance? Does the amount of cores I have access to on heroku affect this in anyway? Also, regardless of which way I pick, what would I be looking to change in the app.py code or would the change solely be inside the procfile?

Assuming I manage to set up multithreading or gunicorn workers, how would this then affect the connection pool set up/what should I do in regards to the connection pool? If anyone familiar with this can help provide some theory or explanations or some resources, I would greatly appreciate it. Thanks all!

Answer (score 0):

From my experience with python here's what I've learned...

1. If you are using multiple threads or async then you need to use a pool or an async connection
2. If you have multiple processes and your code is strictly synchronous with no threads then a pool is not necessary. You can reuse a single connection for each process since they are not shared between each other.
3. Threads dont speed up execution speed in python usually since python will only ever run one thread at a time. Though they can help speed if threads need to block.
4. For web servers the true bottle neck is IO usually, meaning connecting to db or read file or w.e. Multiple process and making those process async gives the greatest performance. Starlette is a async version of Flask... kinda and is usually much faster when setup properly and using async libraries

Comment: what do you mean by "connecting to db"? Like when I do cur = conn.cursor() in psycopg2? Or when I call a select/update/delete statement ?

Comment: The `conn` in `conn.cursor()` is your connection. A cursor is a helper object that lets you query and iterate your results.